# why transition doesn't work on absolutely positioned image?

Tags: html, css, animation, transition

I have an absolutely positioned image inside a relatively positioned container.
Height of image is bigger than that of the container.
I want the image to scroll up to its end using only CSS.
The catch is that height of the image could vary, so it makes sense to make sure that bottom of the image is aligned with bottom of the container once hovered.

Following is the code:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

img:hover {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://voxman.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/whiteonblack.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Atleast explain why this is downvoted? If there is no pure CSS solution then just say it. No need to downvote just because you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a way to position the element equivalent to `bottom: 0px`, but taken for the reference the top .

If you set `top: 100%`, the top of the element will be at the bottom of the parent.
Then, set a `transform` of 100%, and the `bottom` will be where the `top` was.

Notice that this solution works for any image and container height.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0%;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

img:hover {
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://voxman.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/whiteonblack.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Thansk @vals, this is exactly what I was looking for. A pure CSS solution.

Comment: Happy that it helped !

Answer (score 3):

Try `transition` on `transform`

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

img:hover {
  transform: translateY(-60%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://voxman.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/whiteonblack.jpg">
</div>
```

EDIT:

As the height is not set, I'd suggest a jQuery/js solution

```js
$("img")
  .mouseover(function() {
    var offset = -$(this).height() + 200;
    $(this).css("top", offset);
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css("top", 0);
  });
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://voxman.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/whiteonblack.jpg">
</div>

<div class="box">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/Vertical-Banner-EN.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will not be applicable for image of any height. I had already implemented this method as a makeshift solution. But, as mentioned in the question, height of the image could vary.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a transition between `bottom: 0` and `bottom: calc(100% - 18px)`, which is the height of the container minus the height of box2.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 18px;
  bottom: calc(100% - 18px);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.box:hover .box2 {
  background-color: green;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box2">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, try this with working snippet,

```css
.box{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:red;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.box2{
position: absolute;
transition: all 1s ease;
}

.box:hover .box2{
  background-color:green;
  margin-top: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="box2">
test
</div>
</div>
```